# DNS changes on cloudflare to verify domain for SSL not reflecting

Tags: dns, cloudflare, dns-servers

I am using the free version of Cloudflare for my website and I made DNS changes by adding a CNAME record to verify my domain for Ahrefs.

Changes were done 2 hours ago, but they are not propagating on internet. I have been checking on https://dnschecker.org and not even a single server is showing changes.

The CNAME changes are correct as I have checked them several times. Usually it should reflect within 5-15 minutes.

Any reason why this is happening or if there is another way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: DNS propagation does not exist, there is nothing to wait. If you change data in the zone, and test the authoritative nameservers, the new information should be there "immediately".  Otherwise it means a problem at your DNS provider. Then only you can test recursive nameservers. "The CNAME changes are correct as I have checked them several times." You are not showing actual tests you did, and their results, so hard to know what you tested exactly and how. Plus, not giving the actual name involved, noone could troubleshoot things for you.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, problem was not with records it was when you proxy `CName` records it will show it as `A` record if you want to check it with dnschecker.org tools.... Not sure why CloudFlare show CNAME record as A record when its proxed. when you turn off Proxed it shows same record as `CNAME` record...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found solution to my problem, if you add `CNAME` record to `cloudflare` and its `Proxied` then it will show as `A` record when you check propagation on `dnschecker.org` in order for it to work as CNAME record turn off proxy.

I did same and my CNAME started showing on `dnschecker.org`

Learnt something important today.